# Is it possible to bring JFrame to front but NOT focus?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm writing a Java app (Swing GUI) that periodically pops up a JFrame.

Is it possible somehow to bring the window to front (foo.setAlwaysOnTop(true) would be even better) but **without** having it focus?

Some people move their eyes away from the screen from time to time to look at their keyboard while typing, and I'm sure that if this window would always capture the keyboard focus people would get really annoyed as it's causing them to lose quite a few keystrokes every time it pops up unnoticed.

In other cases, even when the user is actually capable of typing without looking at the keyboard all the time, having a window pop up and get focus could cause unwanted actions from the pop-up window itself (some `Tab`+`Enter` combination for example, where the user accidentally selects an option she really wouldn't had selected otherwise).

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

As Jonas suggests, `foo.setFocusableWindowState(false);` seems to work if called after the window has been rendered (tested on Gnome only).

This does not work:

```
foo.setFocusableWindowState(false);
foo.setVisible(true);
foo.setFocusableWindowState(true);
```

However, this **does**:

```
foo.setFocusableWindowState(false);
foo.setVisible(true);
Thread.sleep(1000);
foo.setFocusableWindowState(true);
```

I'll have to see if there's an event I can catch/listen to that allows me to do `foo.setFocusableWindowStatue(true);` when appropriate.

I consider my problem solved.

Comment: did you ever find an event to listen to for when the frame is rendered?

Comment: Did anyone ever find an event to listen to here that worked?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This may work:

```
foo.setFocusableWindowState(false);
```

Comment: This actually seems to work, but I'll either have to set up a timer or find some event to listen to when allowing I do `setFocusableWindowState` back to `true`.

Comment: @Johann you can also try to use `Window` instead of `JFrame`. I think you have more possibilities to control the focus then.

Answer (score 10):

As of Java 1.7 you can call

```
frame.setAutoRequestFocus(false);
```

Comment: This did the trick for me - thanks!

Comment: When `setAutoRequestFocus(false)` on OpenJDK 17/Ubuntu 22 the window no longer pops to front when triggering `toFront()` - but the icon winks. Not what I had in mind though.

Answer (score 2):

I recently ran into the same problem, and the tentative solution has been:

```
JFrame frame = ...;
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
frame.requestFocus();
frame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);
```

Comment: that works if is there only one JFrame, and there isn's any Background Task(s), please start your own thread (if you want then with link to this thread), it's too hard job done that without setVisible(true/flase), but this actions is visible on the screen, answer is use JDialog, only that (meaning Windows OS) you can do that without secondary issues

Comment: That's not at all true, as I have multiple JFrames running in my application. Why start a new thread when the user is describing the same exact issue as I'm having, yet the solution is not complete?  As for JDialog, it isn't always appropriate for the intended purpose of the window, which is my case as well.

Comment: yes maybe I do that without flickering, but this code is longer than this thread, really not good way, don't switch Focus betweens two or more JFrames, bring one JFrame to the another, Focus (same as JFrame or JDialog) came from Native OS and is asynchronous, then so hard to managable,

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: In the GUI Component that creates the Frame, put 2 consecutive calls:

```
frameJustCreated.requestFocus();
this.requestFocus();
```

1st one bring the window of the new JFrame to the top, 2nd one keeps the window where the user is typing at the top.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry! I should have mentioned that this is the only window my program is in charge of. The "other" windows are just other programs the user is running..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call setFocusableWindowState(true) in an event (so, not to wait e.g. 1 second), you can add a WindowListener (e.g. derived from WindowAdapter) that changes the property:

```
    appFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
            super.windowOpened(e);
            e.getWindow().setFocusableWindowState(true);
        }
    });

    appFrame.setFocusableWindowState(false);
    appFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

JInternalFrame `toFront()` calls to `moveToFront()`

Override `moveToFront()`

```
public void moveToFront() {
        Window window = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
        Component focusOwner = (window != null) ? window.getFocusOwner() :
                                null;
        boolean descendant = false;

        if (window != null && focusOwner != null &&
                      SwingUtilities.isDescendingFrom(focusOwner, this)) {
            descendant = true;
            requestFocus();
        }

        super.moveToFront();

        if (descendant) {
            focusOwner.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

the fix is in moveToFront to check if a child has focus, if it does, then temporarily request focus on the internal frame. After the internal frame has movthe ed to front, then request focus back on the previously focused component. This will ensure the appropriate events are generated.

refer 
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4309079